# Query creating issue with ODBC drivers

Tags: asp-classic, odbc

I have a site kitcars.com in Classic Asp and i am facing an issue with it. I just moved my site to a new server. Here, everything works well except one issue with search. When i search for something like "www.luxurykit.com" it shows me the desired result without any error but when i do search again with "hello" it shows this error

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e21' 
>   ODBC driver does not support the requested properties.

I also print the same query and execute it directly in my database and it is working.
I have windows server 2012 with ODBC driver 5.3
Following is my connection code

> strConnString  = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=database; UID=uid;PASSWORD=password; OPTION=3"
>   rs.Open strSql, my_Conn, 3,1

Any idea ?

Comment: Try `rs.Open strSql, my_Conn, 0,1`  The 3 in your code specifies a static cursor, which I don't think is supported by the MySQL ODBC driver, you would need to be using an OLEDB connection (and therefore probably SQL Server).  http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_rs_cursortype.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed now.
Actually, the problem was with the COMMAND TIMEOUT.
Query was taking more than the TIMEOUT time allowed.
So I just made a conn object and used `.commandtimeout()` to increase execution time for query and this FIXED my issue.